# how to find specific class in WP

Tags: javascript, wordpress, class

I have a text that I would like to change ("Happy Clients" in the code below). I tried to find the text on the WP dashboard and in the template editor but with no luck, how can i locate the class so I'll be able to change the text?

```
 <div class="_slider_shadow"></div>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
<div class="count"><div class="count-info"><strong id="targetElem">0</strong><span class="count-description"> Happy Clients</span></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

EDIT
I found a file that contains the following code that is related to text that i want to change:

```
<div class="count"><div class="count-info"><strong id="targetElem">0</strong><span class="count-description"><?php the_field('text_for_count'); ?></span></div></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var endVal = <?php the_field('count'); ?>;
var numAnim = new CountUp("targetElem", 0, endVal - 300, 0 , );
numAnim.start(function() {
    numAnim.update(endVal);
});
</script>
```

Comment: using js you can change the text whatever you want

Comment: is this carousel added dynamical? if so try looking in the database

Answer (score 1):

You can install [`Query Monitor`](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin. It has a section called `Template` which shows all template files that have been used to load the page. That should help you to find what you need.
[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVz3m.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do this :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $(".count-description").text("No Clients");

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Click me</button>

<div class="enigma_slider_shadow"></div>
    </div><!-- /.carousel -->
<div class="count"><div class="count-info"><strong id="targetElem">0</strong><span class="count-description"> Happy Clients</span></div></div>


</body>
</html>
```